# How to create a question in Google Forms that allows two distinct answers?

Tags: google-forms

I have a question like this (it's a DISC test, if this matters):

```
1. From the following list, which option is 100% you and which option is 0% you?
a. tall
b. fat
c. happy
d. unemployed
```

How can I make this possible in Google Forms? The person answering it must be able to choose two of the four options, but they should be distinct (one must be 100% you and the other must be 0% you).

What's the best way to make this work in Google Forms? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible.
You should use the **Multiple choice grid** and turn "Require one response per row" on.

Please have a look at the attached images.

Editing the form:

[image: editing]

Viewing the form:

[image]

Comment: Now, considering the questionnaire is composed of several questions like this, I need to know what option (a,b,c or d) got the most "100%" answers for each person who answers the questionnaire, can it be done?

Comment: @Daniel Yes it can, but this is a completely different topic. What you ask for is the statistical analysis of your data. It can be done in a variety of distinct ways. Through the forms or even better the connected spreadsheets. Things though would get confusing if we were to answer it here.  I think it deserves a question of its own.

Comment: @Daniel This [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92763/117311) may also interest you.